# Usar boton cancelar de daterangepicker en diferentes modulos

Tags: javascript, jquery, daterangepicker

Estoy utilizando la librería de `daterangepicker` pero a la hora de querer realizar una tercera consulta no encuentro la manera ya que el botón de cancelar solo lo puedo utilizar dos veces, de igual manera el código para consultar la el día de hoy, espero alguien me pueda ayudar con una idea.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

```
$(".daterangepicker.opensleft .ranges li").on("click", function(){

  var textoHoy = $(this).attr("data-range-key");

  if(textoHoy == "Hoy"){

    var d = new Date();
    
    var dia = d.getDate();
    var mes = d.getMonth()+1;
    var año = d.getFullYear();

    dia = ("0"+dia).slice(-2);
    mes = ("0"+mes).slice(-2);

    var fechaInicial = año+"-"+mes+"-"+dia;
    var fechaFinal = año+"-"+mes+"-"+dia;   

    localStorage.setItem("capturarRango", "Hoy");

    
        window.location = "index.php?ruta=ventas&fechaInicial="+fechaInicial+"&fechaFinal="+fechaFinal;


  }
})


// CANCELAR RANGO DE FECHAS

$(".daterangepicker.opensleft .range_inputs .cancelBtn").on("click", function(){

    localStorage.removeItem("capturarRango");
    localStorage.clear();

    window.location = "ventas";
    
})
```

Segunda consulta:

```
  // CANCELAR RANGO DE FECHAS

$(".daterangepicker.opensright .range_inputs .cancelBtn").on("click", function(){

  localStorage.removeItem("capturarRango2");
  localStorage.clear();
  window.location = "reportes";
```

})

```
// CAPTURAR HOY


$(".daterangepicker.opensright .ranges li").on("click", function(){

  var textoHoy = $(this).attr("data-range-key");

  if(textoHoy == "Hoy"){

    var d = new Date();
    
    var dia = d.getDate();
    var mes = d.getMonth()+1;
    var año = d.getFullYear();

    dia = ("0"+dia).slice(-2);
    mes = ("0"+mes).slice(-2);

    var fechaInicial = año+"-"+mes+"-"+dia;
    var fechaFinal = año+"-"+mes+"-"+dia;   

    localStorage.setItem("capturarRango2", "Hoy");

    window.location = "index.php?ruta=reportes&fechaInicial="+fechaInicial+"&fechaFinal="+fechaFinal;

  }})
```